# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve a set of data from my collection, but every time I run the code I get an error:

"Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform", and nothing is retrieved from the firestore.

Here is the code:

```
class EnterRefferal extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EnterRefferalState createState() => _EnterRefferalState();
}

class _EnterRefferalState extends State<EnterRefferal> {
  List<String> refId = [];
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("clients")
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
              setState(() {
                querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
                  refId.addAll([doc["refID"]]);
                });
              }),
            });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(refId);
```

Please help me solve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your collection look like in firestore?

Comment: The error message indicates that you don't have a field called `refID` in your `clients`  collection. Could you share your Firestore structure so we can check what you are trying to fetch?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "refID" field exists in your "clients" collections.
Try with this,

**Use**
doc.get('refID') Or doc.data()['refID']

**Instead of**
[doc["refID"]]