# How to add Firestore data into List<List>

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add Firestore data into List to display it in a pdf report, this way wouldn't work properly I mean they not show the data in the list and display some error I don't know what the problem?

> Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform"

```
theData() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('QFS')
      .snapshots()
      .forEach((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    for (int index = 0; index < snapshot.docs.length; index++) {
      List<List> listOfData = [];
      listOfData
          .add({snapshot.docs[index]["commodity"]}.toList());
      print(listOfData);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wouldn't work properly"? How are you using `theData()`? Are you getting any errors? What's the actual and the expected behavior?

Comment: it should return all the data store in firestore: commodity, but it shows this error "Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform"

Comment: Does it exist, though?

Comment: please see the pic 
https://nimb.ws/pdY9Wn

Comment: can you show a snaphot picture of your Firestore

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try optimising your code using forEach() loop instead of for() loop and you should try using docs[index].get(‘commodity’) instead of docs[index][“commodity”].

You can refer to these stackoverflow links for more insight: [Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213155/unhandled-exception-bad-state-field-does-not-exist-within-the-documentsnapshot), [How to fix Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68064217/how-to-fix-bad-state-field-does-not-exist-within-the-documentsnapshotplatform).